# Script not hiding/unhiding objects in render correctly

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I tried my script in the latest version 3.5.1 and 2.93.4 (and I even asked a friend to try it on the latest version too) and my script is not working like it should be and I can't figure out why.

Here is my script (sorry if it's messy) :

```
import bpy

# create metaball for every frame
number_mb = 1

for i in range (number_mb):
    bpy.ops.object.metaball_add(location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1.5, 1.5, 1.5))
    bpy.context.object.scale.x = 1.503
    bpy.context.object.scale.y = 1.503
    bpy.context.object.scale.z = 1.503
    bpy.context.object.data.resolution = 0.1
    bpy.context.object.data.render_resolution = 0.1
    material = bpy.data.materials['hypercube']
    bpy.context.object.data.materials.append(material)



    # get a refrence to the currently active object
    # metaball = bpy.context.active_object

    # metaball in particle system
    bpy.data.particles["ParticleSettings"].instance_object = bpy.data.objects["Mball"]
    bpy.data.particles["ParticleSettings.005"].instance_object = bpy.data.objects["Mball"]

    # change keyframe
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = i + 150
    
    # turn metaball into mesh 
    bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')

    # metaball boolean modifier
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].operation = 'INTERSECT'
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].object = bpy.data.objects["collision"]
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].solver = 'FAST'
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Boolean")
    
     #   copy location
    bpy.ops.object.constraint_add(type='COPY_LOCATION')
    bpy.context.object.constraints["Copy Location"].target = bpy.data.objects["grabby"]
    bpy.ops.object.constraint_add(type='COPY_SCALE')
    bpy.context.object.constraints["Copy Scale"].target = bpy.data.objects["grabby"]


    # metaball subdivision 1
#    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF')
#    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Subdivision"].levels = 1
#    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Subdivision"].render_levels = 1
    
    
    # metaball hide/unhide 
    
    bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = False
    bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport", frame = i + 150) 
    bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = True
    bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport", frame = i + 151)
    bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = True
    bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport", frame = 0)
    
    bpy.context.active_object.hide_render = False
    bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_render", frame = i + 150)
    bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = True
    bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_render", frame = i + 151)
    bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = True
    bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_render", frame = 0)
```

Only the last part where I hide/unhide is important but I'm still sharing the full thing. Basically at frame 0 I hide in the preview and the render the frame, at frame 150 I unhide it, then at frame 151 I hide it again. It works fine in the preview but not the render for some ungodly reason.

If anyone is interested in helping me [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TbcGi94EfvPZRLrWRAkjBQnkNaCXPy3P/view)'s a blend file (I took the script from my full project and made it run in a new blend file with some essential objects). You only need to hit run script beforehand.

*In preview frame 150 and 151*
[image: Preview frame 150]

[image: Preview frame 151]

*In render frame 150 and 151*
[image: Render frame 150]
[image: Render frame 151]

Comment: Please in future edit a [closed post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294410/why-is-the-render-part-of-my-script-not-working) instead of deleting it.

Comment: That's interesting. In the closed question, you posted correct working code, but here it seems you did not change `bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = True` lines to `hide_render` after copy pasting.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you copy-pasted your code:

```
bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = False
bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport", frame = i + 150) 
bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = True
bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport", frame = i + 151)
bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = True
bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport", frame = 0)
```

In order to also hide in renders, but then you only replaced 4 out of 6 occurences of `hide_viewport` with `hide_render`.

Unfortunately while Blender has an option to automatically replace a phrase with another:

[image]

It doesn't have a common option *"In Selection"*. Therefore in order to easily replace all occurences in a given text, by using *"Replace All"* option, <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> cut-paste it to another text block or a text editor of your choice, <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> replace text there, and copy-paste it back to your editor.

The fixed code becomes:

```py
bpy.context.active_object.hide_render = False
bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_render", frame = i + 150) 
bpy.context.active_object.hide_render = True
bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_render", frame = i + 151)
bpy.context.active_object.hide_render = True
bpy.context.active_object.keyframe_insert("hide_render", frame = 0)
```

Even better, consider reducing the duplication of your code:

```py
def keyframe(*, target, frame, state):
    target.hide_viewport = state
    target.keyframe_insert("hide_viewport", frame=frame)
    target.hide_render = state
    target.keyframe_insert("hide_render", frame=frame)
    
ob = bpy.context.active_object
keyframe(target=ob, frame=i+150, state=False)
keyframe(target=ob, frame=i+151, state=True)
keyframe(target=ob, frame=0, state=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

> #### [image: AI Icon] Warning, Potential AI generated content⚠️
>
> **This post is suspected to have been generated with the help of an artificial intelligence, chat bot, or other language model tools without proper attribution.**
>
> There is reason to believe this post was not written by a human due to its structure, and grammatical construction, and has been marked by our community.
> Current AI chat bots are a language models, that means they are like a parrot, they can mimic human language well, but they are built to write **seemingly** logical, **seemingly** factual grammatically valid text, rather than actually **be correct**, like a human would.
> The veracity of the following content cannot be ascertained.
> See the [Concerns regarding AI generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396).

Well Bing rambles on a bit, not the clearest wording but to summarize I believe the TLDR is in the last section, this line:

```
bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = True
```

Should be changed to:

```
bpy.context.active_object.hide_render = True
```

And this line:

```
bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = False
```

Should be changed to:

```
bpy.context.active_object.hide_render = False
```

Or alternatively you could use:

```
bpy.context.active_object.hide_set (True)
```

According to Bing: "It seems that the problem is that you are using the `hide_viewport` property to hide and unhide objects in render, which is not the correct way to do it. The `hide_viewport` property only affects the visibility of objects in the viewport, not in the render. To hide and unhide objects in render, the you should use the `hide_render` property instead.

The solution is to modify the code to use `hide_render` instead of `hide_viewport`. For example, instead of:

```
bpy.data.objects ["Cube"].hide_viewport = True
```

You should write:

```
bpy.data.objects ["Cube"].hide_render = True
```

This will hide the cube object in render, but not in the viewport. To unhide it, you can set the `hide_render` property to `False`.

Alternatively, you can also use the `hide_set()` method to hide and unhide objects in both viewport and render. For example, instead of:

```
bpy.data.objects ["Cube"].hide_viewport = True
```

You can write:

```
bpy.data.objects ["Cube"].hide_set (True)
```

This will hide the cube object in both viewport and render. To unhide it, you can pass `False` as an argument to the `hide_set()` method."

References:

[How to hide a certain object in blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133468/how-to-hide-a-certain-object-in-blender-2-8)

[Hiding objects with scripting - unpredictable behaviour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94320/hiding-objects-with-scripting-unpredictable-behaviour)

Comment: not a good comment. bing ignored whatever you input in it

Comment: i am dumb as hell

Comment: I think the answer would be fine as is without the added AI generated ramblings (which by the way are false, `hide_set` will only hide the object in the viewport, please always double check when you're using AI generated content). Although the other answer by Markus is IMO of higher overall quality.